# Recognise the lost focus event of a DataGrid as a whole, not its controls lost focus

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

## **GOAL:**

I have an WPF/MVVM (mvvm-light to be exact) application where I want to recognise/capture the lostfocus event of the datagid as a whole and bind it to an ICommand in the view model.

The problem is that the lost focus event is fired every time a control within the datagrid loses focus as well as the datagrid itself losing focus.  In my applications I throw a warning (a MVVM type message box) on the datagrid lostfocus event/command if a user tries to "navigate" away from the current view if the viewModle "HasErrors" property is true.  The result is that even if the user moves between controls in the datagrid, the user gets this error/warning.  I only want it when the datagrid as a whole loses focus.

**What makes this hard:**
Simply put, what makes this hard is using the MVVM.  Usually you could just check the FocusManager in the code behind lostfocus event to get the currently focussed element and see if its in the datagrid ([As outlined here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DataGrid-Lost-Focus-46bb4526)).

### **Question:**

Is there a MVVM standard solution to this problem?  I am not so blindly die hard MVVM to never have code behind, I guess I am just wondering if this is one of those times or is there some strategy.option I didn't think about, which is likely.

### **What I tried:**

**FIRST**-  I tried to have **different command parameters** for the different commands.  ie:

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.PreNavigateValidateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            CommandParameter="DataGridLostFocus"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

and for the controls in the datagrid

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.LostFocusValidateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
             CommandParameter="ControlostFocus"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

notice the difference in the command parameters of DataGridLostFocus and ControlLostFocus.  But what happens is that these commands just happen twice, one for each command parameter with the control lostfocus happening first followed by the datadrid lostfocus.

**SECOND**- You will notice the **different command properties/names**.  Even binding the commands to different command objects did not solve this problem.  Both commands will be called, in the same order described above.

**THIRD** The datagrid is inside a grid, which is inside an expander, which is inside a usercontrol.  I tried moving the ICommand triggerbinding up the visual tree to these three elements.  The lost focus event gets fired the same way even when placed on any of these three "parent" objects.

---

I am starting to think I eighter need to find another event that would work or totally rethink how I handle this error trigger for the viewmodels's HasErrors property.

I would appreciate any help in isolating the lost focus event of the datagrid as whole that still follows MVVM standards.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that most of us developers (including myself) have misunderstood MVVM widely for a long time.

This leads to uneeded overcomplications everywhere as we tend to avoid code-behind at ALL, not really understanding that if we were not to place ANY code/logic in the View layer, there would be no  Bindings, no converters, no `RelativeSource`, no XAML at all.

The real spirit of MVVM is to `separate` logic from UI, not to avoid having  any code in the view.

This really means that you CAN and SHOULD resolve the `Focus` issue (which is purely a View concern, btw) via Code-Behind.
However this does not mean that you are going to put any application/business logic in the Code-Behind.

Simply put, just handle any UI events in code behind and then delegate the  logic to the ViewModel:

```
private void DataGrid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataGrid.IsKeyboardFocusWithin) //or whatever UI condition
    {
        //Resolve the ViewModel via DI, constructor injection or whatever. Then:
        ViewModel.DoMyBusinessLogic();
    }
}
```

See what I mean? you're not placing business logic here. The Business  logic is still  in the ViewModel / Model, whereas the View related code (`Focus`) is placed in the Code Behind.

Also, this is exactly what `Commands` do. They react to some event in the View, and then invoke some method in the ViewModel, don't they?

I think this will really ease the pain caused by the strict no-code-behind policy we're used to.

I would also like to hear other people's thoughts on  this

Comment: thanks.  A nice clear explanation that shows how to "handle any UI events in code behind and then delegate the logic to the ViewModel"  I was leaning this way but my solution was not as clean and I was looking for some community feedback.  I know this is a common topic/misunderstanding and I agree that we can overcomplicate things.  I myself had my focus set too much on accomplishing everything through strict binding to ViewModel properties.  Having said that, I still feel like the MVVM approach in general has pushed me to write better more maintainable and testable code.

Comment: I think what is interesting is that my experience is that there is no generally accepted "best practice" for MVVM.  Even the frameworks for MVVM are new and supported by smaller communities (other than prism which is another steep learning curve)  I had a really steep learning curve with MVVM because I found so much different documentation on how to apporach MVVM and much of it was years old.  Even Microsoft who claims to have written large portions of Visual Studio 2012 with MVVM does not clearly document its best practices.  At least what I could find. I hope as MVVM matures this improves.

Comment: @HighCode Just brilliant words. Every methodology or best practice should be adopted rationally or else it will degrade to Cargo Cult